# How i can add onsubmit attribute to <form> in contact form 7 and onclick attribute to the submit button in contact form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

This is my HTML code:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
<input  type="text" id="userInput" />
<input type="email" id="emailId" />
<input type ="number" id="phoneNumber" />
<input  type="submit" onclick="userdetails();" />
</form>
```

How i can implement this in contact form 7 of my wordpress website. Also i have multiple forms on same page so please help how i can target a specific form with the above mentioned attributes..???

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear to me. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to add onclick function to submit button in contact form 7. How i can do that when i have 3 forms on the same page? (each of them have a submit button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it :

```
<form id="form1">
        <input  type="text" id="userInput">
        <input type="email" id="emailId" />
        <input type ="number" id="phoneNumber" />
        <input  type="button" onclick="userdetails();" value="Details"/>
</form>
<form id="form2">
        <input  type="button" onclick="form1.submit()" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Explanation  :

I have replace `type="submit"` by `type=button` so that it doesn't submit the form.
If you need to submit a form you can proceed this way `onclick="form_id.submit()"`.